# How to send PG binary data from the Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgis, binary-data, rails-postgresql, vector-tiles

I have a Postgres database with PostGIS extension and some geo-data in it. I need to generate tiles with custom SQL queries (using `ST_...` functions), that returns binary data (`bytea`, like `\x1a320a0474657374121d12020000180322150946ec3f1a14453b0a09280f091413121e09091e0f1a026331220228012880207802`). And I need to send this data from my Rails controller to the requester, with the headers like `'Content-Type: x-application/protobuf'`.

So, my question is:

1) How to get the binary data from the Database (`Sequel`, `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` ?)
2) How to return this data in the controller action? (`send_data ..., tyle: ''` ?)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean, that you need to use one of postgres function that will generate a binary data as an output and then you need to send this data to the client?

Comment: @AntonTkachov exactly! `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` returns `PG::Result` object, and I don't sure that i can get raw binary data from it.

Comment: 1. Can you provide a sample of your query?
2. Does sql console return you a proper binary string, that you expect?

Comment: @AntonTkachov 1) `SELECT ST_AsMVT(q, 'table', 512, 'geom') AS mvt FROM ( WITH a AS ( SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom( ST_Transform(public.table.wkb_geometry, 3857), TileBBox(13, 2411, 3078, 3857), 512, 256, true ) geom , columns FROM public.table WHERE ST_Intersects(TileBBox(13, 2411, 3078, 4326), public.table.wkb_geometry) ) SELECT * FROM a WHERE geom IS NOT NULL ) AS q` , 2) yes, in form of Postgres (see example in my answer). How can I get raw data from PG::Result?

Answer (score 3):

I just figured out the solution - hope it helps, although it's a long time ago..

```
records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
result = records_array[0]['st_asmvt']
encoded = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.unescape_bytea(result)
```

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.unescape_bytea` is the answer.